# how to to filter data category wise in filemaker pro 12?

Tags: filemaker

I am working on filemaker pro 12. I made 3 tables category, product and product_catalog. category table having two fields-
(1)cat_id 
(2) category

product table having fields-
1- pr_id
2- category(dropdown list)
3- pr_name
4- price

product catalog having fields-
1- category(dropdown list)
2- product(dropdown list)
3- price

I fill the dropdown fields using value lists . I want on product catalog , when anybody choose any category then next dropdown show only that category products..
I also related the tables from cat_id to category Of product_category of product. product code to product of product table. Have any body solution..???
Thanks in advance...............

Answer (score 1):

In your value list definition, try the "only show related records" option.